# Spring rest controller in management port?

Tags: spring-boot

When using **spring-boot**, how to you expose a controller at management port, the port defined by *management.port*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I ended up implementing

```
org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.MvcEndpoint
```

This exposes the Controller into management port rather than application port.

Answer (score 1):

In Spring Boot 2.x it is done using `@RestControllerEndpoint` annotation. For example if you define following properties in application.yml:

```
management:
  server:
    port: 8081
  endpoints:
    web:
      base-path: "/actuator" # default value
```

and some controller as `@RestControllerEndpoint(id="debug")`, it will be mapped as

http://localhost:8081/actuator/debug/...

More info:
https://www.javadevjournal.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-actuator-custom-endpoint/